# The multi-part identifier could not be bound - SQL Server 2016

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

```
SELECT clm.CLCL_PAYEE_PR_ID, clm.SBSB_CK, clm.CLCL_ID, clm.clcl_id_adj_to,clm.clcl_id_adj_from, clm.CLCL_PAID_DT
FROM ODW.DW.fac_cmc_clcl_claim CLM
INNER JOIN ODW.DW.fac_cmc_meme_member MEME ON MEME.meme_ck = CLM.meme_ck
INNER JOIN ODW.DW.fac_cmc_mepe_prcs_elig MEPE ON MEPE.meme_ck = MEME.meme_ck
INNER JOIN ODW.DW.fac_cmc_mepr_prim_prov MEPR ON MEPE.meme_ck = MEPR.meme_ck AND CLM.clcl_prpr_id_pcp = MEPR.prpr_id
INNER JOIN ODW.DW.fac_cmc_sbsb_subsc SBSB ON MEME.sbsb_ck = SBSB.sbsb_ck
INNER JOIN ODW.DW.fac_cmc_prpr_prov PROV ON MEPR.prpr_id = PROV.prpr_id AND PROV.prpr_mctr_prty = 'RISK'
INNER JOIN ODW.DW.fac_cmc_prer_relation PRER ON PRER.prpr_id = MEPR.prpr_id
INNER JOIN ODW.DW.fac_cmc_plds_plan_desc PLDS ON MEPE.cspi_id = PLDS.cspi_id
INNER JOIN ODW.DW.fac_cmc_pdds_prod_desc PDDS ON MEPE.pdpd_id = PDDS.pdpd_id
WHERE CLM.clcl_paid_dt BETWEEN '2019-12-24 00:00:00.000' AND '2019-12-30 23:59:59.997'
AND CLM.clcl_cur_sts = '02'
AND CLM.clcl_cl_type = 'M'
AND CLM.clcl_cl_sub_type = 'H'
AND CLM.grgr_ck IN (46)
AND MEPR.grgr_ck IN (46)
AND MEPE.grgr_ck IN (46)
AND MEPE.mepe_elig_ind = 'Y'
AND CLM.clcl_low_svc_dt BETWEEN MEPE.mepe_eff_dt AND MEPE.mepe_term_dt
AND CLM.clcl_low_svc_dt BETWEEN MEPR.mepr_eff_dt AND MEPR.mepr_term_dt
AND SBSB.grgr_ck IN (46)
AND PRER.prer_prpr_entity = 'I'
AND PRER.prer_prpr_id IN ('64456546')
AND (PLDS.plds_desc LIKE '%risk%' OR PDDS.pdds_desc LIKE '%risk%');
```

This query runs in PROD with different variables which substitute the value of the hard coded values. It runs around 100 times per day in PROD and on some days some of the runs fail due to this error:

> The multi-part identifier "PDDS.pdds_desc" could not be bound

Please note that all the joins are being done on views.

When I re-run the failed process, it succeeds the second time with no changes to the underlying query.

Can anyone suggest what could be the issue. Also, any performance optimization suggestions for this query query will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: My only guess is someone is changing the definition of the `VIEW`.

Comment: On a different note, things like `PRER.prer_prpr_id IN ('64456546')` and `AND MEPR.grgr_ck IN (46)` seem odd. Why not use `=` instead of `IN`?

Comment: The view definitions are not changing as other processes running the same query with different parameters run fine at the same time. Also, I am using IN as there could be multiple grgr_ck and prer_prpr_ids associated with different processes. But thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: But you only have a singular value in there, @Abhi, and `SBSB.grgr_ck IN (@SomeScalarVariable)` would still be the same as `SBSB.grgr_ck = @SomeScalarVariable` in your parametrised version. Some like `SBSB.grgr_ck IN ('1,2,3,4')` won't work as you expect, it would be the same as `SBSB.grgr_ck = '1,2,3,4'`; which if you're querying against an `int` column would generate a conversion error.

Comment: @Larnu - So, when there are multiple grgr_cks associated with the process, the query runs as SBSB.grgr_ck IN (1,2,3,4). These comma separated values are directly picked from a column in another table. Not the best data modelling, but that is how it was implemented when I joined the team.

Comment: Which means that doesn't tally with your statement *"This query runs in PROD with different variables which substitute the value of the hard coded values.*" If a clause like `MEPE.grgr_ck IN (46)` is parametrised with a table type variable, then the syntax would be `MEPE.grgr_ck IN (SELECT [column] FROM @TableVariable)`. This suggests we don't have the actual SQL.

Comment: @Larnu - Not trying to refute your comment but consider this. `MEPE.grgr_ck IN (@v_grgr_ck) where @v_grgr_ck` is calculated as: `SELECT @v_grgr_ck = grgr_ck FROM TBL1 WHERE Col1 = <some value>`. Now grgr_ck column in TBL1 could be a single value or comma separated values. I think my statement "This query runs in PROD with different variables which substitute the value of the hard coded values." still stands but I am sure you are more experienced than me, so any issues in formulating my statement should be overlooked over the "multi-part identifier could not be bound" issue.

Comment: That isn't how SQL works, @Abhi. SQL doesn't take something like `WHERE SomeColumn IN (@TableVariable)` and translate that, it would error. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=adcb9b9f95187eb8438c9442f273990e)

Comment: @Larnu - Now, I understand your comment. So, this whole sql query is generated dynamically and then executed when the actual values have been substituted. I have provided the final query in my post and I think that is sufficient for the scope of the issue here. But, thanks for your suggestions and time on this.